# How to make background-size: cover cut from left?

Tags: html, css

Consider this simple W3 School  background image example, I changed its `background-size` to `cover`.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size

If shrinking the page, you can see that the mountain image starts to cut from right to left. I wonder if I could change this effect to cut from left to right? I.e. when cutting starts, the left side gets cut off first.

Comment: adjust the background-position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`background-position: right;`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-position) to set the origin of the background-image to the right side of the container:

```css
#example1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 25px;
  background: url(https://placehold.it/1000x100);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <p>The background image is displayed in its original size.</p>
</div>
```

You can also use the [`background`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#propdef-background) shorthand property to solve this:

```css
#example1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 25px;
  background: url(https://placehold.it/1000x100) no-repeat right / cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <p>The background image is displayed in its original size.</p>
</div>
```